# validation error on an object in spring mvc

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

```
@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

    Date today = new Date();
    MiniStatementViewModel miniStatementViewModel=(MiniStatementViewModel) target;


    else if(miniStatementViewModel.getFinancialTransactionType()==null)
    {
    errors.rejectValue("financialTransactionType","financialTransactionTypeNull");
    }
```

this is my validator code in this financialTransactionType is in model as an FinancialTransactionType of object

```
public class MiniStatementViewModel {


private boolean isMiniStatement;

private Date fromDate;

private Date toDate;

private String accountCode;

private FinancialTransactionType financialTransactionType;
```

So, when I show an error msg on JSP gives an error msg like

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type mkcl.os.apps.solar.account.model.FinancialTransactionType for property financialTransactionType; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type mkcl.os.apps.solar.account.model.FinancialTransactionType for value NONE; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class mkcl.os.apps.solar.account.model.FinancialTransactionType.NONE
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means you are getting String value `NONE` from your form, and, in order to fit that value in `financialTransactionType` field it performs FinancialTransactionType.valueOf("NONE") and it returns an error because it doesn't exist.

Change your class to:

```
public class MiniStatementViewModel {


private boolean isMiniStatement;

private Date fromDate;

private Date toDate;

private String accountCode;

private String financialTransactionType;
```

and your validator:

```
@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

    Date today = new Date();
    MiniStatementViewModel miniStatementViewModel=(MiniStatementViewModel) target;


    else if(FinancialTransactionType.valueOf(miniStatementViewModel.getFinancialTransactionType())==null)
    {
    errors.rejectValue("financialTransactionType","financialTransactionTypeNull");
    }
```